# Как записать строку Unicode в файл C++

Tags: файлы, unicode, c++

Есть строка Unicode типа BSTR. В ней могут храниться любые символы: русские, английские буквы, иероглифы. Ее неоходимо корректно записать в простой текстовый файл. Русские и английски символы лекго записываются через fputs(), но есть проблема и иероглифами и другими нацианальными символами. Как это можно сиправить? Пишу на Visual Studio, но использовать .net нельзя!

Comment: @VladD, Error 2 error C2782: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&,const _Elem)' : template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous e:\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\exceltask\exceltask\xmlparse.cpp 160 1 ExcelTask
строка: folders[0]=string(dirname)+"\\xl"+ _T('\0');

Comment: @Павел Воевода: ну так это конечно не скомпилируется, `string(dirname)` — это «узкая» строка, а `_T(...)` — либо «узкая», либо «широкая», в зависимости от настроек (Multi-byte или Unicode). Явный баг. А этот код внутри библиотеки? Тогда библиотека не очень, конечно.

Comment: @VladD, ну вот такие дела. мне надо строку bstr или wstring записать в файл, но он записывает ее в кодировке ansi. Может, стоит просто поменять кодировку этого файла, но вот что-то не знаю, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Павел Воевода: Ну, я бы выкинул эту библиотеку (если в ней такие баги есть, наверняка ещё куча других) и прикрутил какую-нибудь другую. Тем более, если записью в файл занимается библиотека, тут вы ничего исправить не сможете.

Ну или может скорее будет самостоятельно написать то же самое вручную :-)

Comment: @VladD, в файл нужно самому запись реализовать

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от того, в какой *кодировке* вы хотите записать ваш файл.

- Если это UCS-2, достаточно просто использовать [`fwputs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fputws).
- Если это utf-8, вы можете сконвертировать вашу строку из/в utf-16 [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809553/276994).

Comment: у ТС там bstr, а это utf16. fwputs скорее всего заработает как нужно, если только в настройках проекта выставить unicode режим.

Comment: В настройках проекта стоит Multi-Byte Character Set. Без него просто не компилируется другая библиотека

Comment: @Павел Воевода: Хм. А зависит ли внутренняя кухня `bstr` от настроек проекта? Скорее всего нет (попробуйте!). Но вообще-то использовать MBCS-target в 2013 году совсем неправильно, что за проблема с библиотекой?

Comment: @VladD, там библиотека вообще написана на чистом C, она используется для распаковки Zip-архивов. А проблемы там с TCHAR возникают.

Comment: @Павел Воевода: А зачем вам `TCHAR`? `TCHAR` не нужен, вы должны по идее точно знать, где «узкая», а где «широкая» строка. Или это библиотека пользуется `TCHAR`'ом? Тогда проблема может быть и на вашей стороне, например, если вы передаёте ей `char` там, где она ожидает увидеть `wchar_t == TCHAR`. Покажите, где именно не компилируется.

Comment: @VladD, там библиотека использует TCHAR в своей реализации, поэтому пытаться что-то исправить в ней нет смысла. Мне б просто решить свою проблему и все парочкой преобразований типов хотя бы.

Comment: @Павел Воевода: А всё же, что именно не компилируется в случае с Unicode-проектом?

Comment: @VladD, error C2782: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&,const _Elem)'
вот такие подобные ошибки везде, где работа со строками происходит

Comment: Не, это не ошибка, это название типа. А какая строка в _коде_ не компилируется?